# How to use enum to do comparison? (typescript)

Tags: typescript, enums

I have the following typescript code:

```
if ((viewerConfig.locked) % 3 == 1) {
    //do stuff
}
```

I was told that "For these types of checks where you compare against a constant, make an enum instead to do the comparison"

I am not exactly sure what this means or how to implement this. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Any value that has a remainder of 1 when divided by 3 would be a pretty long enum.

Comment: @RutherfordWonkington - `4` ?

Comment: What even is `3`? What is `1`? What do these values *mean*? Give then names that express that and (maybe) put then in an enum. Although I think a simple constant is more appropriate.

Comment: And 10, 13, 16, etc. ad infinitum.  If you just want to check if the value is 4, why not make a simple comparison?

Comment: @RutherfordWonkington - ok, so by pretty long enum you mean there are many values that satisfy the condition.

Comment: Yes, in fact infinitely many!

Comment: @RutherfordWonkington well, in *theory*. In JS, you can't represent every number ever, so it's still *a whole lot of* numbers but not technically infinite.